# Use browser level scroll instead of Grid Level (table level) scroll in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to show data but while using it I have 2 scroll bars one at grid-level and another at browser level I want to use browser level scroll bar for ag-grid. I didn't find any clue in the ag-grid documentation to implement this.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way for you to suppress vertical scrolling in ag-grid, unless you set a very large height value to its container. However, this might end up with a large amount of negative space in your page. I'd suggest you to adjust the height of the ag-grid container so that the browser scrollbar does not appear.

Comment: Can you at least add a quick mockup of what the page should look like? Is a grid the _only_ thing you want on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `domLayout` property for this.

Refer to this example how they have set `domLayout = "autoHeight"` and how it is being used: [ag-grid Auto-Height](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#example-auto-height)

> domLayout:    Set to 'normal', 'autoHeight' or 'print' to switch between layout options. The default is 'normal'.

Comment: autoHeight breaks row virtualization, so something to be aware of if you have lots of data. Infinite scrolling will also try to load all the 'pages' rather than wait till the user scrolls to the end of the list.

Comment: @Tija - are you sure? check on the example link I've provided. Even after `autoHeight`, row virtualization is still working - verify it after doing `F12`.

Comment: I looked at the elements tab in dev tools and it's definitely adding the missing columns as you scroll right. This is because it knows the width of the container, however it doesn't know the height of the container until all rows are rendered and it needs to calculate that to figure out the height. So row virtualization breaks for rows, it also seems to make all the infinite scroll calls  to get all the data in my testing. This link describes it in more detail..https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#auto-height

Comment: correct. Here, OP's ask is to display browser level scroll - not grid level scroll. In this scenario, `domLayout` is fine. Otherwise, yes, it's not wise to have this for performance related reason.