# setting domLayout = 'autoHeight' crashing the browser

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In order to use the browser level scroll instead of grid level scroll I made `domLayout = 'autoHeight'` which actually did what I wanted but it is crashing the browser is there any solution to this, I searched for this but didn't find any solution, if anyone have solution for this even a reference link would be helpful.

Comment: Don't use `domLayout: 'autoHeight'`. If you want a better answer, ask a better question and [provide requested information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589587/use-browser-level-scroll-instead-of-grid-level-table-level-scroll-in-ag-grid#comment92116536_52589587). This is (at least) your second question about the same thing, and I'm still not sure what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this, you are getting rid of row virtualization, so you are actually loading as many rows you are passing at once, note that this is not an ag-grid limitation, this is just the fact that you are passing too much data and running out of memory

If you have too much data, in ag-grid you are going to have either pagination or scroll, so that the rows are virtualized and then you don't crash the browser

Hope this helps